# Android: Sqlite update only if date newer

Tags: android, sql, database, datetime

i have a table with one row of value String datetime() and a id (and some more).

Now I want to update WHERE id = xx and ONLY WHEN my.Datatime is newer that the stored datetime. 
How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "your datetime" is '2012-12-12', then

```
WHERE id = xx
  and '2012-12-12' > Datatime
```

Comment: thanks. another question: is is not ensured that the entry is existing. how would the sql statement look like ? something like insert if exist update if not